# When should reviewers skip code edits for technologies they are not familiar with?

Tags: discussion, edits, specific-edit

**Update:** The first line of the answer to [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260246/2152970)--which this question is referenced as a possible duplicate--states:

> When in doubt, click 'Skip'. "Learn to love that Skip button."

It also points out that code edits which fix obvious errors to answers should be encouraged. Looking through the **DO**s and **DONT**'s of that section, I believe that my edits fit the bill for a good edit (see my original post for reference to the changes I attempted to make). My edits were small enough that they did not warrant a new answer, more difficult to explain in a comment than just submit an edit, and obvious enough for a reviewer with basic understanding of typescript to recognize that the edit did not change the intent, especially when put in context with whole post.

So, I would like to understand from the perspective of someone who is really just trying to improve an answer on Stack Overflow, at what level of understanding (or code complexity) should a reviewer click skip?

Based on my experience so far (see original post below), it seems that reviewers might be overeager to reject something than admit they might not have enough knowledge to verify the edit. How much knowledge should a reviewer have in order to approve or reject code edits? Especially very simple edits. Wouldn't it be better for the community if reviewers skip code edits for technologies they know they have no background in?

Furthermore, my edits were rejected by a vote of 2:1 both times, which leads me to believe there is some uncertainty among reviewers regarding when to reject, accept, or skip a review that deals with an edit to code in an answer.

**Original post for context:** I tried to make the same edit twice on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55472255/how-do-i-add-svg-files-via-maticonregistry-in-unit-tests/55528306#55528306) to correct invalid code in the answer. Both times my edits were rejected on the grounds that

> This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits
>   that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of
>   the post's owner.

How is correcting invalid syntax "deviating from the original intent"? The code is obviously invalid. I would assume the author's original intent is to provide a valid test component to mock the `MatIcon` class. By mistake, the author added component metadata to the bottom of the class and my edit simply removed it.

What do I need to do to get these edits approved? This should not be that hard. Am I missing something?

The attempted revisions, for reference:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24403383
https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24469267

**Personal note:** I now realize that I could have done a better job explaining my edits, but I have to say that my experience so far has been rather discouraging. I made an edit that I believed would be an obvious improvement to anybody with a background in TypeScript and/or Angular. At this point I am wary of making code edits here again because the effort seems too great to get even a simple edit approved.

Comment: Reviewers are not expected to be experts in the particular programming language in the question so they do not know if your change is valid or not. They will generally reject significant changes to code. Edits to code are not recommended.

Comment: The change was not significant and I guess I hoped that on a site specifically for coding questions, that correcting obvious syntax errors would be welcomed. Typescript is a widely used language and a quick use of any online editor would verify that the code is invalid.

Comment: Have a look at the [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260246/11682469).

Comment: The FAQ says: "Unlike questions, making an answer work is a good thing and should be encouraged with a few guidelines to follow." And under the Do's:   `Test your edited code to make sure it works` and  `Fix syntax errors and typos`

Comment: This would have been resolved much sooner had you simply made your edit summary say "The selector and template properties belong in the Component decorator, not in the class body." Or, you know, added that as a comment in addition to the edit summary for the benefit of the OP. Getting on a high horse about the rules of editing helps few; communicating your intent helps many.

Answer (score 11):

As one of the reviewers who rejected your suggested edit: When I see edits that change code *content* (not formatting), I will almost always reject them.

This is because such an edit is 'invisibly' (to many) changing the poster's answer - and that, in my opinion, is **not** what editing should do.

This "code correction" (and almost all others like it) should be suggested as a comment, then left to the original poster to correct the code (or to reject it, if that is their opinion).

One exception would be a very minor code change, such as correcting an obvious typo.

Comment: This line of thinking flies directly in the face of the FAQ linked by Jeanne Dark, which  states that fixing code should be encouraged. I would challenge you to skip rather than reject if you are not familiar enough with the code to see the obvious syntax errors.

Comment: @ender Not at all! That link, for example, says **DO** Fix typos (misspelled function calls, variable names, etc.), unless they are relevant to the question but **DON'T** Change the code logic or functionality.

Comment: But it does not change code logic or functionality. I use this code for my test suite at work I can very clearly demonstrate that the two properties added at the end of the class, with the crazy string types of `'mat-icon` and `<span></span>` are very clearly typos.

Comment: @ender Then clearly demonstrate that to the OP in a comment!

Comment: Either way, it seems futile (if not provocative) to re-submit an identical edit after it has been rejected once.

Comment: My whole point is that these are obvious typos that could easily be corrected by the community without having to wait on one person, the OP, to get around to answering my comment.

Comment: @ender comment can be easily seen by someone with good knowledge of the topic AND full editing rights. Such person can make the edit too if author is nowhere to be found. Rejected edits are pretty much impossible to see by anyone but original author (who still can accept the change).

Comment: I did want to provoke a response. I wanted the reviewers to take a little more time to review the code changes because I believe that it's good for the community for reviewers to be honest about their knowledge, and not reject revisions out of hand because they aren't familiar with the technology.

Comment: @ender (non welcoming comment) - I strongly recommend to stop trying to turn this question into "why those newcomers not willing to do research before posting" - the topic discussed on meta soo many times it's not funny.

Comment: I'm not trying to be funny and I am not bashing newcomers who write answers (By my point totals you might consider me a newbie). Typos happen to the best. I am trying to make the case that reviewers should skip reviews like this if they are not familiar enough with the technology to approve a correction of obvious errors. In both submissions on my part, at least one reviewer accepted my changes.